# Rendering on any point in ARCore

Tags: android, opengl-es-2.0, arcore

I have been working on and exploring ARCore for the past few days. I saw this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GFhpAe10qnk>) from Scope AR. I noticed that they are freely rendering the arrows wherever they touch (ex: on the engine). From what I have understood , you can only render at points or planes identified by ARCore. My question is how they are rendering the arrows without even knowing if that point(where the person taps on the screen) is actually identified by ARCore?

Answer (score 3):

They are using a Microsoft Hololens, it has nothing to do with ARCore.